# How to get path property of Sitecore item using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

how can I get path property of Sitecore item using PowerShell module?

Answer (score 4):

You can get item properties using this command.

```
$itemID = "{8A87AC2B-210D-49F2-93FC-215918085418}" #Mention your Item ID

# Use Format-Table if you want to show results in the table view.
Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "$itemID" | Format-Table -Property ID, Name, DisplayName, "Page Title", @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.Paths.FullPath} }

# Use Show-ListView if you want to show result in a popup window 
Get-Item -Path "master:" -ID "$itemID" | Show-ListView -Property ID, Name, DisplayName, "Page Title", @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.Paths.FullPath} }
```

The window will also give you the option to export. Like this.

[image]

Read this article for more operations.

https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/working-with-items

Answer (score 2):

You can get the path of Sitecore item through Powershell Script:-

```
Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content/Home" | Show-ListView -Property `
    @{Label="ID"; Expression={$_.ID}},
    @{Label="Name"; Expression={$_.DisplayName}},
    @{Label="Path"; Expression={$_.Paths.Path}}
```

Update the path of Sitecore item `"master:/sitecore/content/Home"`. To get the path  of item, Click on the item in Sitecore Content tree and have a look at the **Quick info** tab and copy the `Item path`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have the item as a variable and just want the Sitecore path, it is simple:

```
$item.Paths.Path
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$item = Get-Item master:/content/home
Write-Host "Item path: " $item.FullPath
```

It will give following output

**Item path:  /sitecore/content/Home**

We can get item by Id and access all item property like this.

```
$item = Get-Item -Path  master: -ID {110D559F-DEA5-42EA-9C1C-8A5DF7E70EF9}
Write-Host $item.Paths.Path
```

We can get more example here:
https://gist.github.com/Adamsimsy/30dc60df837c1400e6fccd814b3dc752